# powershell catch export to csv not working

Tags: powershell, csv, try-catch

I'm writing a script that is fed a .csv and tries to make an operation and then catches into a seperate .csv but for some reason I cant seem to feed the catch info into the csv. I get the error, "Export-csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again."

I appreciate any input from the brains.

```
#imports a csv and does somthing with the data. The columns in the csv are specified by the $($_.'columnName')
Import-Csv -Path 'PathToMyCSV.csv' | ForEach-Object{
    
    #Print associated User
    Write-Host  "$($_.ModifiedEmail)" -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline;
    Write-Host " is the user's email prefix, " -NoNewline


    #Print PC name to be moved
    Write-Host "SD-LT-$($_.PCName)" -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline;
    Write-Host " is the PC they use, and " -NoNewline



    #Print The OU the computer is moving to
    Write-Host "$($_.OU)" -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline;
    Write-Host "is the OU the computer needs to go in!"
    
    $pcname = "SD-LT-$($_.PCName)"

    Try {
    Get-ADComputer SD-LT-$($_.PCName) | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $($_.OU)
        }

    Catch  {
       Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Magenta 
       $pcname | Export-csv -Path 'PathToAnotherCSV.csv' -Append -Force
         }

    }
```

Comment: Your symptom is mystifying, given that the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet has no `-Name` parameter.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly how your code looks? As mklement0 pointed out, the error message is saying that your trying to use the argument `-Name` on `Export-Csv` tho we can't see that on your code which is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `PSCustomObject`.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{'pcname'=$pcname} | Export-csv -Path 'PathToAnotherCSV.csv' -Append -Force
```